# Flutter dialog widget with dynamic resizing on navigation

Tags: flutter, dialog, resize

I am trying to build a dialog widget that has some nested navigation. When pressing a button on that widget, I want it to navigate to the dialog content associated with that button. The size of the dialog screen should then also resize to predefined dimensions, so that the content can fit within the dialog. With my implementation the navigation works as expected, but the dialog does not resize upon navigation.

Below is my minimal reproducible implementation:

**Main page widget:**

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainPage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
                context: context, builder: (context) => const MainDialog());
          },
          child: const Text('Show Dialog'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Dialog widget:**

```
class MainDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainDialog({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MainDialog> createState() => _MainDialogState();
}

class _MainDialogState extends State<MainDialog> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Navigator(
          key: GlobalKey(),
          onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const LargePage(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: const Text('Large Page'),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const SmallPage(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: const Text('Small Page'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Large page for dialog widget:**

```
class LargePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LargePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const SizedBox(
      height: 800.0,
      width: 600.0,
      child: Center(
        child: Text('This is the large page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Small page for dialog widget:**

```
class SmallPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SmallPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const SizedBox(
      height: 200.0,
      width: 150.0,
      child: Center(
        child: Text('This is the small page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As stated, the navigation works as expected, but the dialog box does not resize. All I am expecting is that you navigate to the larger dialog, then the dialog box will expand to the size of the child.

I would really appreciate your help with this. Thank you all kindly in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the size of the MainDialog, all you can get is the custom size of the page over MainDialog because you are pushing the large/small page over MainDialog.

```html
class LargePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LargePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      child: Center(
        child: Text('This is the large page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SmallPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SmallPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(50),
      child: Center(
        child: Text('This is the small page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```